# How to place order with custom payment gateway module using JS / Ajax?

Tags: magento2, custom, payment-gateway

I am integrating a custom `payment gateway` module in `Magento 2`. 
How can I use  `JS/ajax` on the checkout page on click of place order trigger some `js` event?

As I need to pop-up a modal on click of place order and prevent the submission from creating the order and check for payment response with `js` and then submit the checkout form with payment response.

Any Idea how this is possible ?

Comment: have you checked the official documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/get-payment-info.html?

Comment: I am new to `Magento 2`and Yes, I've checked this documentation also. but things are not clear. I have a module like  `app/code/Vendor/Module`
I have built the module from .`mage2gen.com`